# Installing a package from a server location

Tags: python

Currently building a program which requires certain packages. I have created multiple scripts which automatically install these from a folder. Locally (with internet) this works fine, but on the server (no internet) it keeps trying to connect to the internet.

I've put the packages in a folder and I refer to this folder in the Python script.

Following code works locally, but not on the server:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
importpath = os.getcwd() + '\Packages'
os.chdir(importpath)

try:
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    print('Openpyxl is already installed')
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pip
    pip(['install', '--user', 'openpyxl-2.5.11.tar.gz'])
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

How can I make it so that PIP will only install from the specific tar.gz and will not try to connect to the internet?

Edit: Install paths have to be relative

Answer (score 1):

Use `--find-links` argument.

Following example installs package from current directory and all dependencies would be searched in `~/packages`

```
pip3 install --find-links=~/packages .
```

Comment: hi @grapes, thanks but still getting this error: py :   Url '~/Packages' is ignored. It is either a non-existing path or lacks a specific scheme.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the path has to be relative. Thing is, I'm defining a relative path at the top of my script. It is also processing the tar.gz from that specific path

Comment: Something like this: `pip(['install', '--user', '--find-links=' + os.getcwd() + '\Packages', 'openpyxl-2.5.11.tar.gz'])`

Comment: It breaks on collecting `jdcal`. Are you sure, this `jdcal` can be found in your local `packages` folder?

Comment: I manually installed it and now it works. Had to do the same thing for pandas. Thanks for your help Grapes